# Remove referrer information while redirecting page in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, referrer

For example, i have an application which redirects to www.google.com. Response.redirect will send the redirect information to the external address which i dont want. However internally, i want to access the referrer information. Is there any way to remove that information. Will redirecting from javascript using window.location = 'www.google.com'; help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the referrer will get removed if you launch the URL in a new window.  In JavaScript that would leverage the window.open(...) function.

Comment: I want to open the url in same window

Comment: If you are working within the same window and redirect, you cannot remove the referrer.

Comment: Yes you can remove the referrer even in the same window. See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30304058/2440