# Hide referrer on iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

Is it possible to remove referrer when using iframe?
here the case:

I have a page at http://www.mywebsite.com with an `<iframe>` in it. Like this:

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body>
  ...
<a href="#loadiframe">SHow Website</a>
  <iframe id="#loadiframe" src="http://www.iframetarget.tld">
  ...
 </body>
</html>
```

i want to iframetarget.tld not contains referrer/can not see if mywebsite.com is loading their pages.

is that possible?

Note: iframe will load using jQuery lightbox/colorbox

Comment: you want to fool google.com ? :)

Comment: No, it's for loading external site without noticing the iframetarget owner.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 20):

None of these answers worked for me, but [MDN's iframe reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-referrerpolicy) states that setting the `referrerpolicy` to `no-referrer` will accomplish this and it worked for me. Support in older browsers will be hit or miss.

Example:

```html
<iframe src="https://whatsmyreferer.com/" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<iframe id="#loadiframe" src='javascript:window.location.replace("http://www.iframetarget.tld")'>
```

It works.

Answer (score 1):

Using an iframe with a javascript location redirect works:

```
<iframe style="display:none" src="javascript:parent.location.replace('http://www.whatismyreferer.com/'+(parent.location.hash||''))">
```

Note that on some browsers when using HTTP, the *last* referrer  will always be sent, which will be domain owning the iframe. Using HTTPS (and a valid certificate) ensures a hidden referrer on all browsers tested.