# Remove referer from Javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, http-headers, referrer

I need to do a Javascript based redirect

```
window.location.href = 'URL';
```

But I need to remove the referrer from the HTTP headers upon redirection (the target page should see no referrer), how can I do that?

Comment: Here is a simple trick using iframes and https: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30304058/2440

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<a href="redirecturl" rel="noreferrer" id="autoclick">Link</a>
<script>document.getElementById('autoclick').click();</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is but as far as I know it's not beautiful. Check the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817595/remove-http-referer)

Comment: That's not just *not beautiful*, that's plain fugly. And it's so terribly hacky I wouldn't depend on it. Furthermore, it only works for linking images, **not for redirects, nor can it**, so it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you only going to do this for location redirect, then you can set up a bridge page hosted somewhere less sensitive and doesn't do anything other than redirect. Now you can link all the destination to `http://<redirect_page>?<actual_url>`

window.location.href= window.location.href.split("?")[1];

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has been inactive for a while, found it browsing the web and found a nice answer that may help save another person's time. This version uses JQuery.

```js
$(function(){

  $("#button").on("click", function(){
      $("head").append('<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>');
      window.location = "http://www.example.org";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button">Click to navigate</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't. It's up to the browser to set referrer headers or not, the script has no influence on it.